# Java short delay

Tags: java, text, timer, output

I have been trying to create a way to recreate the pokemon's "Rolling text" where one letter appears at a time. The problem is being able to create a timer short enough to make it reasonable.

This is what i have tried:

```
public static void roll(String text) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < text.length()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
    i++;
    }
}
```

This will work fine if i set the value in Thread.sleep to anything above 250. The problem is, if i set seconds below 250 then it will wait the entire length of time (If i tell it to wait 100 millisends 100 times, it will wait 10 seconds) before outputting anything.

Im not sure if this is a problem with the type of timer itself or if there is something else at play here.

Comment: @jonathon Does it take 1 sec or 10 sec as 100 ms 10 times is 1000 ms or 1 sec

Comment: Sorry, i meant 100ms 100 times for 10 seconds.

Comment: @JonathonM its strange, it just worked fine for me...

Comment: You should get in the habit of handling interrupts properly.  When a thread is interrupted, it means some other code is asking you stop what you are doing.  Ignoring it and continuing essentially makes your code a rogue thread.  The best thing you can do is remove the try/catch entirely, and add `throws InterruptedException` to your method's signature.  If you don't want to do that, at least put the try/catch *around* your loop rather than inside it, so the loop terminates when requested to do so by the interrupting thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.out.flush();` to force the buffer to be written out.

Comment: Where would i need to put this? Putting it after System.out.print(text.charAt(i)); didnt resolve anything. Also should i be using any parameters?

Comment: @JonathonM How are you running the application? In an IDE such as Netbeans, or on the commandline?

Comment: @JonathonM That may affect it, my Eclipse seems to print it nicely even without a flush. If Netbeans really does prevent the flushing, it's not really nice. You can run it from the command line and see if it works better.

Comment: Thanks, ill be switching to eclipse now! Netbeans was used by my teacher so i just stuck with it. Never had a problem with it until now.